# Entity Query in Query, is it possible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, postgresql

I'm not really sure how to ask this question.  I need to create an object, I believe it is called a projection, that has the result of one query, plus from that need to query another table and get that object into the projection.

This is a C# WCF Service for a Website we are building with HTML5, JS, and PhoneGap.

**EDIT:** Getting an error on the ToList (see code) -   "The method or operation is not implemented."

**EDIT3:** changed the Entity Object company_deployed_files to IQueryable AND removed the FirstOrDefault caused a new/different exception Message = "The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.\r\nParameter name: argument"

Background: This is a kind of messed up Entity Model as it was developed for Postgresql, and I don't have access to any tools to update the model except by hand.  Plus some design issues with the database does not allow for great model even if we did.  In other words my two tables don't have key constrains(in the entity model) to perform a join in the entity model - unless someone shows me how - that honestly might be the best solution - but would need some help with that.

But getting the below code to work would be a great solution.

```
public List<FileIDResult> GetAllFileIDFromDeviceAndGroup ( int deviceID, int groupID)
     {

     List<FileIDResult> returnList = null;

     using (var db = new PgContext())
        {
        IQueryable<FileIDResult> query = null;
        if (deviceID > 0)
           {
           var queryForID =
               from b in db.device_files
               where b.device_id == deviceID
               select new FileIDResult
               {
                  file_id = b.file_id,
                  file_description = b.file_description,
                  company_deployed_files  =  (from o in db.company_deployed_files
                                                where o.file_id == b.file_id
                                                select o).FirstOrDefault(),
                  IsDeviceFile = true
               };

           if (query == null)
              {
              query = queryForID;
              }
           else
              {
              // query should always be null here
              }
           }


        if (groupID > 0)
           {
           var queryForfileID =
            from b in db.group_files
            where b.group_id == groupID
            select new FileIDResult
            {
               file_id = b.file_id,
               file_description = b.file_description,
               company_deployed_files  = (from o in db.company_deployed_files
                                             where o.file_id == b.file_id
                                             select o).FirstOrDefault(),
               IsDeviceFile = false

            };

           if (query != null)
              {
              // query may or may not be null here
              query = query.Union(queryForfileID);
              }
           else
              {
              // query may or may not be null here
              query = queryForfileID;
              }
           }

       //This query.ToList(); is failing -  "The method or operation is not implemented."
       returnList = query.ToList ();
        }

     return returnList;
     }
```

**Edit 2** 
The ToList is throwing an exception.

I'm 98% sure it is the lines: company_deployed_files  =  (from o in db.company_deployed_files where o.file_id == b.file_id select o).FirstOrDefault()

**End Edit 2**

Comment: What's wrong with it? Any exceptions?

Comment: Sorry buried that in the code, will edit question.

Comment: I've seen this before in EF providers for other RDBMSs. Make sure the version of the provider you're using is up to date. I bet if you looked at the `ToList<T>` extension method for that provider you'll find a `throw new NotImplementedException()` there.

Comment: @Cory Query providers don't provide their own `ToList` implementations...that's a BCL method, and it's simply what executes the query, thus allowing the problem with some earlier query provider to actually be thrown.

Comment: Start breaking your query down into smaller pieces.  Executes the sub queries, start bringing them together slowly adding each operator one at a time until you find out which operator is the operation that's not supported.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, my mistake. What I was seeing before was for some custom aggregrate function in LINQ to NHibernate and not `ToList`.

Comment: @Servy it worked until I added the: company_deployed_files  =(from o in db.company_deployed_files where o.file_id == b.file_id select o).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @Servy I should take that back.  I also made two other changes.  The using (var db = new PgContext()) was added, the db was a reference back to another, but can't use reference in the second query - and because of this change don't need it in the earlier method.  Also the ToList was in the earlier Method.

Comment: @BrianHanf Figure out just what you need to remove for the query to execute properly, slowly narrowing down just the smallest piece that you need to remove for it to work.  See if removing the sub-query allows the query to execute, if it does, start pulling out pieces of it to see if something in particular in the sub-query is the problem.

Comment: @Servy worked when I removed the two lines: company_deployed_files =(from o in db.company_deployed_files where o.file_id == b.file_id select o).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Great, that's one step, now continue on with the process I suggested to you.

Comment: @Servy changed the Entity object company_deployed_files to IQueryable< company_deployed_files > get a different exception. - Message = "The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.\r\nParameter name: argument"